# How to auto-resurrect pm2 after system restart

Tags: pm2

I have set up the jobs in pm2 and used command `pm2 save`. If the server unfortunately crashed and restarted, i had to check and manually run `pm2 resurrect` to restart all saved jobs.

Is there any solution that whenever server reboots `pm2 resurrect` is automatically called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows server, you could add a script in task scheduler that runs on boot:

```
SET PM2_HOME=D:\PATH\TO\PM2\DIRECTORY
pm2 resurrect
```

Comment: how do it in linux server?

Comment: For linux-based servers, you can use pm2 startup then pm2 save

***The startup command will generate another command which you need to execute as root on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try execute in your terminal the following command:

`$ pm2 startup`

For more information:
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/